# Density of polynomials in $L^2(\mathbb{R},d\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, polynomials

My question concerns a generalised version of the following fact from standard functional analysis books:

The space $\mathbb{C}[x]$ of (complex-valued) polynomials on $[0,1]$ (or any other compact of $\mathbb{R}$, of course) is dense in $L^2(0,1)$, with the usual Lebesgue measure.

The latter fact can be shown with a two-step argument: (1) the continuous functions $C([0,1])$ are dense in $L^2(0,1)$, with $\|f\|_{L^2}\leq\|f\|_{L^\infty}$; (2) by Stone-Weierstrass $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is dense in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{L^\infty})$.

Now, the new setting I'm wondering about is this. Let $\mu$ be a (positive regular Borel) measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that all monomials $x^n$, $n=0,1,2,\dots$, are integrable. (For example: $d\mu(x)=e^{-x^2}dx$.) In particular, $\mu$ is a finite measure. Thus, $\mathbb{C}[x]\subset L^2(\mathbb{R},d\mu)$ and its closure in the $L^2$-norm is a closed Hilbert subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R},d\mu)$. I am to understand from indirect claims I found on various textbooks that *in general* such a closure subspace is *not* the whole $L^2(\mathbb{R},d\mu)$, i.e., the polynomials are not necessarily dense in such $L^2(\mathbb{R},d\mu)$.

Is that true? Can anyone give me an example of lack of density? From the argument above on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure at least I can save the inequality $\|f\|_{L^2}\leq \mathrm{const}\times\|f\|_{L^\infty}$ and also a standard density like the $C^\infty_0$-functions into the $L^2$-functions still holds true. So, where does the approximation mechanism break up?

Thank you!

Comment: exercise 8.7 of T J Sullivan’s intro to UQ says to try mu as the density of the lognormal distribution. Ok, this is an example on the positive half line but I’m guessing it’s not hard to extend to R...